# FIlter Sitecore Form Dropdown Value based on other dropdown

Tags: sitecore-forms, custom-field

I have custom drop-down fields that read data from API's.
I have lot of records in 1 dropdown around 30k. SO i need to filter dropdown value based on value selected in first dropdown.
How to handle that scenario.

Comment: You need to create cascading droplist for Sitecore Form. Refer this link https://blogs.perficient.com/2023/09/07/create-custom-cascading-dropdown-list-element-in-sitecore-form/